# Hide WKWebView to avoid VoiceOver recognition ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, webview, accessibility

I have a webview (`WKWebView`) which is added to `UIView` (`WebViewContainer`) which is inside a `UIViewController`. After a button event, a `UIView` (center view) is added to `UIViewController` view on top of webview.

I am trying to hide the webview when the Center View shows up so that VoiceOver does not speak the webview contents. But currently its all not working.

I have the following code which tries to hide the webview but it still captures the webview contents and talks back to the user through voice over.

How can I not let the VoiceOver not read the webView Contents ?

UPDATES: Even after hiding the view and view not being appeared voice over does talk back about the WebView. Is this an apple bug ?

```
self.webView.accessibilityViewIsModal = false;
self.webView.hidden = true;
 addChildViewController(centerView);                    
 self.view.addSubview(centerView.view);
 self.webViewContainer.accessibilityElementsHidden = true;
 self.webView.accessibilityElementsHidden = true;
 self.webView.isAccessibilityElement = false;
 self.webViewContainer.isAccessibilityElement = false;
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I want to post my solution.
WKWebView seems like handling accessibilityElements.
The following wrapper can hide the entire web view from VoiceOver.

```
@interface WKWebViewWrapper : WKWebView
@end
@implementation WKWebViewWrapper

- (NSInteger)accessibilityElementCount
{
    return 0;
}

@end
```